# Django: unable to create Generic Foreign key object

Tags: django

I'm using **Django 2.x**

I have two models

```
class DynamicUrlObject(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.Char(max_length=50)
    my_obj = fields.GenericRelation(DynamicUrlObject, related_query_name='my_obj')
```

I have an object of **MyModel** and want to create a record for **DynamicUrlObject** and link same to the **MyModel** model.

I'm doing it something like

```
dy_obj = DynamicUrlObject.objects.get_or_create(
    content_object=my_existing_obj,
    domain='http://example.com'
)

my_existing_obj.my_obj = dy_obj
my_existing_obj.save()
```

But this is not creating a record for **DynamicUrlObject** and gives an error as

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'content_object' does not generate an 
automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. 
If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.
```

Comment: which line is causing the error? why do you try to assign the field `my_obj` again? There's no need for that. After you've created `dy_obj`, the reverse relation exists, i.e. `my_existing_obj.my_obj` should return `dy_obj`. Also your `GenericRelation` should be a plural since it's a one-to-many relationship. You can't assign it.

Comment: But the error is pointing to line `domain='http://example.com'`. I commented that line then it points to line above that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `filter` or `get` directly on a generic foreign key [1], so `get_or_create()` won't work. If you know the type of `my_existing_obj` is `MyModel`, you can use the `GenericRelation` you set on `MyModel`:

```
try:
    dy_obj = DynamicUrlObject.objects.get(my_obj=my_existing_object, domain=...)  # use the `related_query_name` here
except DynamicUrlObject.DoesNotExist:
    dy_obj = DynamicUrlObject(content_object=my_existing_object, domain=...)
    dy_obj.save()
```

Also once you've created `dy_obj`, you don't need to assign the reverse relationship to `my_existing_object`. The `GenericRelation` isn't a concrete field in the db, it's just a way for django ORM to know how to name the relationships.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey